# Web.config rule for rewriting url is always redirected from https to http

Tags: php, azure, iis, web-config, nette

I have a issue with the web.config and forcing SSLs. I have a rule for rewriting url, because Nette PHP site is hosted.

```
<rule name="Rewrite Admin" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^admin/(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />    
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/index.php" />
               </rule>
```

In case I use *https* in url, the request is always redirected to http. (https://example.com/admin -> example.com/admin). When I use rule for SSL force below for all requests then error occur (Too many redirects). (have a 2 rules in web.config)

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
          <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(node)" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(cbre)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
      </rule>
```

How to force ssl for action type "rewrite"?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I took your `rule` config but cannot reproduce the issue. So, to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS, I'd recommend you install a site extension called `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` via Kudu.

1. Open the browser and visit:

   ```
   https://<your-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/#gallery
   ```
2. In search box enter "*redirect*", then click **Search** button.

   [image]
3. Select `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS` and click **ADD** button.
4. Click **Install** button when the dialog opens.
5. To make it available by clicking **Restart Site** button.

Comment: This solution caused me the same issue. Too many redirects. The problem is when you use the rule for rewriting, always http (Even though https) is returned.

Comment: Have you removed `Redirect to https` rule from web.config file?

Comment: Yes. I've removed. I have 3 types of apps in one hosting. Angular app in root, PHP nette in two folders. Could it be caused by Nette redirect?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Nette. However, I tested your web.config and it worked fine on my site.

Comment: Thanks. It was caused by Nette. It is necessary to use flags in router. $flags = Route::SECURED; $router[] = new Route('<presenter>/<action>[/<id>]', 'Shops:default',$flags);